# CSS not working in Chrome with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I have following code:

```
<div id="results" class="results" style="height: 590px; overflow-y: scroll"></div>
```

The id results will be filled by ajax. Firefox shows Scroll bar but Chrome does not display it.

Can anyone help me ? Here is the testing site too http://beta.elasticbeanstalk.com/

Comment: You are missing a `;` after `overflow-y: scroll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it have something to do with this line of [your css](http://beta.elasticbeanstalk.com/assets/main-a904101e21bab32ce37699b96df2ae6b.css)?:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Yes, yes it could.

Comment: It did not work, removing this code or setting display: block is applying scrollbar in item box but not in results div.

Comment: In you code, there might be the case that for Chrome browser, somewhere intentionally hiding scroll bar. The code by [KyleMit](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1366033/kylemit) is right.